# If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence then show that $\liminf (-a_n ) = -\limsup(a_n)$

Tags: real-analysis

Could any one please help me figure out this question:

> If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence then show that $\liminf (-a_n ) = -\limsup(a_n)$.

Please, I am having trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

$\liminf b_{n}$ stands for $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_{n}$ where $c_{n}:=\inf\left\{ b_{k}\mid k\geq n\right\} $
and $\limsup b_{n}$ stands for $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_{n}$ where $d_{n}:=\sup\left\{ b_{k}\mid k\geq n\right\} $.

In that light we have $\liminf\left(-a_{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf\left\{ -a_{k}\mid k\geq n\right\} $

Now observe that $\inf\left\{ -a_{k}\mid k\geq n\right\} =-\sup\left\{ a_{k}\mid k\geq n\right\} $

That leads to $\liminf\left(-a_{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}-\sup\left\{ a_{k}\mid k\geq n\right\} =-\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\left\{ a_{k}\mid k\geq n\right\} =-\limsup a_{n}$

Answer (score 1):

If you just apply the definitions, you see that what you want to show is
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\inf_{m > n}(-a_m)\right) = -\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sup_{m > n}(a_m)\right)
$$
It is a standard exercice in supremums and infimums to show that for *any* set $X$, we have $\inf(-X) = -\sup(X)$ (as long as they exist) (if you haven't shown this before, do it!), so we actually have
$$
\inf_{m > n}(-a_m) = -\sup_{m > n}(a_m)
$$
for *any* $n$, which clearly implies equality once we take the limit as $n \to \infty$.